# Opening port on mac os x (mavericks) for nodejs

Tags: firewall, home-server, node.js

I am running a node.js app locally and would like to make it available for demo for outside world. It is running on port 3000.

I have added `node` to the firewall to allow incoming connections but still it is not possible to open connection to port 3000 from outside. It works locally though (i.e. localhost:3000).

Comment: By 'from outside', do you mean over the local network or from the Internet? For the case of a request from the Internet (i.e. behind a NAT), you may need to set up port forwarding.

Comment: @yjwong from the internet.

Comment: Have you done port forwarding?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1. The macOS firewall**

`System preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall -> Firewall Options… -> "node" should have "Allow incoming connections"` to expose the Node server to the network.

**Step 2. Start Node with the right IP address**

When starting the Node server you would usually use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for development, this prevents the server from being exposed. When you want to expose the server to the network you should use IP address `0.0.0.0`.

Be careful when exposing your server. It is **very easy and dangerous** to expose a development Node server to the network on e.g. a café. A bad person can discover your server on the network and open your website at e.g. `http://192.168.0.100:3000`. If your server is running in development mode and perhaps has authentication disabled, then the bad person can easily "log in" and explore your product/code as well as the data in the connected database.

**Step 3. Set up port forwarding on your router**

In the web interface for your router, find **port forwarding** and set some port (e.g. 42000) to map to your computer's internal network address with port 3000.

The Node server on your computer should now be accessible via the internet at your routers public IP address and port 3000.

(There may be more layers beyond your computer and your router.)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried various ways but by far the easiest was to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download).

```sh
brew install --cask ngrok

ngrok

# That gave the instructions...
#
#   Sign up for an account: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/signup
#   Install your authtoken: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken
#
# Once i followed the instructions (took 2mins) I did...

ngrok http 3000

# And that was it, i could access 
# my http://localhost:3000 local server
# from anywhere in the world.
```

*Note: I'm on a mac. You can get ngrok for other platforms.*